# How to pre select all values of input control by default in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

How to select all values of input control by default on the launch of the report?

Comment: What do you mean? Your question is unclear

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a list input control and you have a fixed number of values in the list, you can select them by setting the Default Value Expression for your parameter to this (filling in the appropriate values):

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(new String[] {
    "Value1",
    "Value2",
    "Value3"
});
```

If you make the input control optional, the user could leave the selection blank to select all values also.  This is generally the way I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Tom's solution works if report's scripting language is set to Java. Otherwise for Groovy it gives an error something like:

```
Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: calculator_*: unexpected token
```

In the case where you have to use Groovy (e.g. for simpler date manipulation - $P{inputDate}.plus(1)), simply set Default Value Expression for your parameter to this:

```
["Value1","Value2","Value3"]
```